# Rails 5.1 app in Docker: bundle install fails at mini-racer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, rubygems

I have got a Rails app that runs locally on my Mac and I am unable to deploy it to a Docker container. The Dockerfile runs without problem up to the statement

```
RUN bundle install --deployment --without development test
```

The error I get is

```
Installing mini_racer 0.6.2 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory:
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mini_racer-0.6.2/ext/mini_racer_extension
/usr/local/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20220512-6-jda14.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lpthread... yes
creating Makefile

current directory:
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mini_racer-0.6.2/ext/mini_racer_extension
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory:
/usr/local/bundle/gems/mini_racer-0.6.2/ext/mini_racer_extension
make "DESTDIR="
compiling mini_racer_extension.cc
cc1plus: warning: command-line option ‘-Wimplicit-int’ is valid for C/ObjC but
not for C++
...
cc1plus: note: unrecognized command-line option ‘-Wno-constant-logical-operand’
may have been intended to silence earlier diagnostics
linking shared-object mini_racer_extension.so
g++: error:
/usr/local/bundle/gems/libv8-node-16.10.0.0-x86_64-linux/vendor/v8/x86_64-linux/libv8/obj/libv8_monolith.a:
No such file or directory
make: *** [Makefile:262: mini_racer_extension.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

I am using Rails 5.2.7, Ruby, 2.6.10, Bundler version 1.17. The Docker image I start with is `ruby:2.6`. (It **is** an old project.)

I have found https://github.com/rubyjs/mini_racer/issues/218, but the workarounds there don't help me. I have tried adding `x86_64-linux` in the section `PLATFORMS` in Gemfile.lock, substituting it for the `PLATFORMS` entry `ruby` and removing Gemfile.lock altogether. As I see it, the installation process for mini-racer is faulty for my image, which AFAIK runs Ubuntu.

As the container build fails, so it never gets set up, a manual correction afterwards is not possible. Is it possible to specify a mini-racer version (I am currently locked at 0.6.2) to avoid the problem? Or is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The first thing I did was to comment out `RUN bundle install...` and all following commands in the Dockerfile (since this was the point where things started going wrong) except `ENTRYPOINT`. But I replaced the contents of my docker-entrypoint script. Instead of trying to start passenger, I inserted `tail -f /dev/null`, which never terminates.
Then I added a line `tty:true` to my `docker-compose.yml` file in the section of the container that failed. (AFAIU this creates a terminal into the container equivalent to `docker exec -t`).

Then docker-compose succeeded and the container stayed up and running.

This made it possible to enter the running container using `docker exec -it ... bash` and so debug my configuration directly in the running container. It turned out that all I needed was `gem 'mini_racer', '< 0.5.0', platforms: :ruby` in my Gemfile.

I hope this detailed answer helps someone else.